# Проверка email-адреса при регистрации

Tags: php, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Хочу сделать проверку email адреса при регистрации на стороне клиента, с помощью JavaScript, и на стороне сервера с помощью PHP.

В JavaScript использую такое регулярное выражение:

```
var pattern = new RegExp (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/);
```

Вопрос - как с помощью jQuery проверить поле формы с id="email"?

```
$('#email').value.match(pattern)?
```

В PHP создал такую функцию:

```
//Проверка e-mail с помощью php (на стороне сервера)
function validateEmail(email)
{
    $pattern = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) 
    {
        return "Введите корректный email адрес.<br>";
    }
}

validateEmail($email);
```

Однако после такой проверки у меня в браузере выскакивает 500-ая ошибка, скажите в чем ошибка в коде?

Comment: Лучше делать проверку введенного email через smtp сервера. Библиотека на GitHub для этого: https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=smtp+email+validator&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php 
    function validateEmail($email) {
        $pattern = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
            return "Некорректный email";
        } else {
            return "Верный email";
        }
    }
    echo validateEmail("test@test.ru");
?>
```

Вообще лучше возвращать не строку, а результат.

JS:

```
 $(function (){
     $("#form").submit(function(e){
         var email = $("#email").val();
         alert(!!email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/));
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

[Посмотреть на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XPzR/)

**UPD:** Твои ошибки.

В jQuery к значению input обращаются через $(selector).**val()**

В php при объявлении функции переменная указывается как и везде, **с символом $**

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а то я даже расстроился вчера, потому что ничего не получалось))