# Как верно сделать регулярку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Суть в том что в переменой $page есть HTML код определённой страницы на которой есть E-mail адреса (разные и [@ya](/users/74/yarkov-anton).ru [@mail](/users/5223/mailfornothing).ru @gmail.com итп)

как будет выглядеть регулярка?
и как будет выглядеть код для её применения и сохранения результатов в файлик?

Answer (score 1):

[Проверка email-адреса при регистрации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119193/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-email-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

```
\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+
```